# SwiftUI Form Number Input

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I was wondering if there is a predefined number input in SwiftUI for macOS which looks like this:

[image: swiftui number input]

It is a casual Apple number input consisting of both the TextField and two increase and decrease buttons.

Comment: I think `Stepper` is the closest thing but I think the arrows are in a different position

Comment: yes, I suppose its a TextField combined with a Stepper

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    HStack {
        Text("Widths")
        TextField("", value: $input, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            .frame(width: 50)
        Stepper(value: $input, in: 1...8) {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you a lot!! <3